# JavaScript value to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#test").click(function() {
  getQuerystring(this);
  return false;
});

function getQuerystring(el) {
  console.log(el.href);
  var getUrlParameter = function(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = el.href.split('?')[1],
      sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
      sParameterName;

    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
      sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

      if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
      }
    }
  };

  var blog = getUrlParameter('c');
  //document.getElementById('detail').innerHTML = blog;
  document.cookie = "blog = " + blog;
}
</script>
```

html code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: dashed; size: auto;">
  <a name="divtest" href="#detail?c=active" id="test">testing</a>
</div>
<div id="detail" style="border: 2px; size: auto;">
    <?php
    $chk = $_COOKIE['blog'];
    echo $chk;
    ?>
</div>
```

The JavaScript code should set the cookie, and then php get the values saved in the cookie. I basically want to send value from JavaScript to php on the same page. but it seems to be an error "Notice: Undefined index: blog in C:\wamp64\www\test\ajax.php on line 40". I have searched a lot but didn't find the proper solution. How can I correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path_to_ajax_file",
    type: "post",
    success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById(“result”);
    }
 });
```

HTML code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: dashed; size: auto;">
<a name="divtest" href="#detail?c=active"  id="test">testing</a>
</div>
<div id="detail" style="border: 2px; size: auto;">
  <span id=“result”></span>
</div>
```

Ajax code:

```
echo $_COOKIES[“blog”];
```

So first create HTML structure then call ajax in javascript by jquery and last create ajax file.

Comment: In JavaScript make sure you use ordinary `"` marks for strings - oblique quotes won't work.

Comment: sorry i was typing that on mobile

Comment: thanu soo much. it worked for me. so finaly i found someone wo geniunly helps.

Comment: @Coder no problem, i am glad to help you.

Comment: just help me out in one thing that is url: "path_to_ajax_file", what this file contains.

Comment: In this jquery you calling file named for example “ajax.php” and then you get result and just print it to span

Comment: @Coder you are welcome, if you have some any other problem just post on stackoverflow.